# sx-sref not being compiled to href

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have the following directive that I'm using to generate links (among other things). I've simplified it somewhat here:

```
    oActivityModule.directive('activityDetails', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    activityLog: '@',
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                    element.html(details(angular.fromJson(scope.activityLog)));
                }
            };
        });

        function details(oActivityLog) {
           return '<a sx-sref="channels.channel({channelID: ' + oActivityLog.channelId + '})">' + oActivityLog.name + '</a>';
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the sx-sref tag is not being compiled to a href tag, it looks like in the source html page:

```
<a sx-sref="channels.channel({channelID: 123})">A channel name</a>
```

My routes and everything are all setup fine. I'm using sx-sref in other parts of my application where it is being compiled, however in those cases the sx-sref is in a template html file, not a angular directive js file.

Note, there is a lot more logic (not shown) in the above js directive file to generate the data for the link, which is why I just can't place the link in HTML.

Maybe its something to do with the element.html(...) call?

```
element.html(details(angular.fromJson(scope.activityLog)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to inject $compile, pass it as an argument to the directive function, then call $compile(...)(scope) on the string:

```
       oActivityModule.directive('activityDetails', ['$compile' function ($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    activityLog: '@',
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                    $compile(element.html(details(angular.fromJson(scope.activityLog))))(scope);
                }
            };
        }]);
```